# Racket (Scheme) program to find day of week given date

Tags: racket

I'am trying now to create a racket program that displays an entered date (between 01.01.2000 and 31.12.2100) as a day.

best regards Keyane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [time-related](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html) libraries should be able to help here.

```
#lang racket

(require racket/date)

;; Given a day, month, and year, return the weekday
(define (day-month-year->weekday day month year)
  (define local-secs (find-seconds 0
                                   0
                                   0
                                   day
                                   month
                                   year
                                   #t))
  (define the-date (seconds->date local-secs))
  (vector-ref #("sunday" "monday" "tuesday" "wednesday" "thursday"
                         "friday" "saturday")
              (date-week-day the-date)))
```

For example, the date that I'm writing this in my area (November 17th, 2012) is a Saturday, and the `day-month-year->weekday` function supports this as well:

```
> (day-month-year->weekday 17 11 2012)
"saturday"
```

[July 20, 1969](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11) should be a Sunday:

```
> (day-month-year->weekday 20 7 1969)
"sunday"
```

Comment: first of all: thank you for the answers. @ dyoo i got the the following error "read: #lang not enabled in the current context" and then i just removed #lang racket and i got this one "define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 2 extra parts"

Comment: The code above is written in professional-level Racket.  It is not easily usable directly from the teaching language variants such as Beginner Student Language, as it uses several advanced-level features that an introductory CS instructor will not allow.  If you are allowed to use professional-level Racket, see: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/intro.html to find out how to set the language level to `#lang racket`.

Comment: Thanx, it works now. But how to convert this code in beginner-langauge?

Comment: Let me state this more directly: the code above will not work in Beginner-level language.  That is, if you were trying to use this as a homework solution, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

[Zeller's congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) is the algorithm that you will want to look at. It should be fairly straightforward to translate the algorithm from the math to Racket code.

Side note: when asking StackOverflow, it helps to ask a more specific question and to phrase it as a question. It may also help to state what you have tried already.

Comment: Hi, the input should be in the form: day month year
and as output I expect the weekday on which that date e.g.      (check-expect (date->day 1 1 2000) 'Saturday)

Comment: Why should I believe you that `(date->day 1 1 2000)` be `Saturday`?  More precisely, how would you do this without a computer at hand?